# How to set up Chrome Developer Tools in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome-devtools

Looks like there is a change, I used to install Chrome Dev tools in Eclipse using
http://chromedevtools.googlecode.com/svn/update/dev

Now the url is not accessible any more.

[image]

How to install Chrome Dev Tools in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update site seems to no longer exist, so you'll have to proceed slightly differently to install the Chrome Dev Tools. Bear in mind that they haven't been maintained for several years, so may not work properly in recent versions of Eclipse.

Go to the [Downloads](https://code.google.com/archive/p/chromedevtools/downloads) page of the project and download the `chromedevtools-0.3.8-wipbackends-0.1.10-site.zip` archive. In Eclipse, on the background window you show in your screenshot, click *Add...* and then *Archive...* . In the file explorer that shows up, select the archive you have just downloaded and just go through the installation steps as usual.